# How to implement a view for different columns width on each row in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-view

I have trying to implement a UI and there are different columns on each row. After googling, I found a library [twowayview](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view). But I can't find any example for 6th image in picture in `twowayview`.

How can I implement it using that library or are there another ways without using library? Any example or idea would be appreciate.

Comment: Off the cuff, `GridLayoutManager` with `RecylerView`, and an appropriate `SpanSizeLookup`, would handle this.

Comment: Unless you want to use just a regular `Layout` you should probably do just what @CommonsWare said: `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager` + `SpanSizeLookup`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32763621/1993204)